# Can't get a message through RestUserMessage

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Faced a strange problem. After initializing any command, I cannot receive a message when the user add reactions. DebugMode doesn't show me any exception, the program continues to run, but the code just stops at the line getting the message. The strange thing is that after restarting the program, if the command is not initialized, I can get messages from the channel.

In this GIF, I pre-initialized the command "hi".
[image]

Command code:

```
public class Module : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("hi")]
    public async Task Hi()
    {
        string hi = "Hi";
    }
}
```

OnReaction code:

```
private async Task OnReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3)
{
    IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await arg2.GetMessagesAsync(2).FlattenAsync();
    var message = (RestUserMessage)await arg2.GetMessageAsync(messages.First().Id); //Just stops the execution of the code after use any command
}
```

Comment: If the code stops executing, it's because it threw an exception. Wrap your code in try{ (code) } catch(Exception e){ Console.WriteLine(e); } to find out what the error is and debug it.

Comment: @230Daniel I completely forgot about try catch, I'm just starting to learn C # and don't know much. I caught the error `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Discord.WebSocket.SocketUserMessage' to type 'Discord.Rest.RestUserMessage'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `arg2` only accepts `SocketUserMessage` and I tried to do it through `RestUserMessage`. Although it is still unclear why messages that existed before the bot started can be retrieved via `RestUserMessage`, and new messages that were sent by the bot are only read by `SocketUserMessage`.

My code:

```
private async Task OnReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3)
{
    IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await arg2.GetMessagesAsync(2).FlattenAsync();
    var message = (SocketUserMessage)await arg2.GetMessageAsync(messages.First().Id); 
}
```

Comment: Socket entities are pulled from cache. If a message existed before the bot was online then that message won't be in cache. When working in a scenario where you can either get data from cache or from a rest request, it's best to simply use the interface ... IUserMessage.